# Whenever I'm using $_GET to get a specific row in my DB jquery/JS does nothing

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I'm trying to create an app with jquery/php/mysql. It's supposed to first list all stores in the database, and that works fine. But when you click on one you should get more information on that specific store. And that's where the problem starts.

Basically, everything works fine if I want to fetch all rows from the database. But when I'm trying to use a querystring to select a specific row it doesn't work. I have tried a lot of things and I've seen that it's the $_GET in my php file that makes the jquery function break and doesn't output anything at all. Even if I only do an echo on the GET it breaks it. And I can not understand why. It works good if I just "select * where id = 2" for example. But not when using GET to get the querystring of 2 for example.

(also, right now this is just JSON, but later I will of course need the cross-domain of jsonp)

This is my php code:

```
<?php

// Settings for accessing the DB.

$host = "localhost";
$db = "mappdb";
$username ="db-username";
$password ="******";

// Connect and query the DB and get the data for all attractions

$connect = mysql_pconnect($host, $username, $password) or die("Could not connect to the database");
mysql_select_db($db) or die("Could not select the database");

$arr = array();

$idnumber = $_GET["pid"];


$result = mysql_query("select * from attractions where id = $idnumber");



while($object = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    $arr[] = $object;
}

echo '{"attractions":'.json_encode($arr).'}';

?>
```

And here is my jquery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <title>Store Finder</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="page">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">  
            <a href="index.html" data-icon="back">Back</a>
            <h6>Search</h6>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">

                <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" id="listed" data-filter-placeholder="Filter cities or stores..." data-inset="true">
                    <script type="text/javascript">

                        $(document).ready(function(){
                            var url="http://localhost/mapp/json.php?pid=2";
                            $.getJSON(url,function(json){
                                // loop through the stores here
                                $.each(json.attractions,function(i,dat){
                                    $("#listed").append(
                                    '<li><a href="viewstore.html?id='+dat.id+'">'+dat.id+' '+dat.name+'</a></li>'
                                    ).listview('refresh');
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    </script>


                </ul>


            </div>
            <div id="msg"> </div>

            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <h6>Footer</h6>

            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Been sitting with this the whole day and can't for the life of me figure it out. Would greatly appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you access 'http://localhost/mapp/json.php?pid=2' directly in the browser?

Comment: Never use string interpolation for SQL strings. Seriously:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection. Also consider [CORS headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing#CORS_relationship_to_JSONP) instead of jsonp.

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) because what you're doing here is extremely dangerous. As pointed out by others, you cannot use `mysql_query` in new applications, it will be removed in future versions of PHP, so it's necessary to switch to a modern interface like [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) for compatibility reasons. Sorry for jumping all over you, but a tiny mistake like this can have enormous consequences.

Comment: Thanks guys. No worries on the jumping. :) This is really helpful. I did a lot of php coding before, but it was many years ago. I've already switched to using PDO now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Security Advisor

First of all, you have some pretty major security issues with your code

1. You are using mysql_* functions, which are deprecated in any supported version of PHP. Please use mysqli_* or PDO instead
2. You use a user paramter `$_GET['pid']` directly in a query, which makes your app vulnerable to [SQL Injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection).
   Please refer to google search for countermeasures and get this fixed asap!

### Your problem

most likely lies with `$.getJson()`.
First I'd make sure the `?pid=2`-part is really appended to your url by looking into your Browsers Firebug/Developer Tools' Network Tab to see the URL which is called.
I think it omits the pid entirely.
This can be fixed by calling the function like this:

```
var url = "http://localhost/mapp/json.php
var data = { 'pid': 2}; 
$.getJSON(url, data, function(json) {
    ...
});
```

According to the [$.getJSON() manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) this function takes 3 arguments.
First the url, second a plain data object and third a callback function in case of an success.
`data` wil be treated as a list of query parameters which are urlencoded and appended to your url.

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem. It works great now. 
And thanks for the security advice as well. Will look into all of that.

Comment: You're welcome :) As a good start into SQL Injection & other security topics I recommend [Padraic Brady's take on SQL Injection](http://phpsecurity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Injection-Attacks.html#sql-injection) in his PHP security book.

Comment: Thanks! :) Will definitely look into that.